# YouTube JavaScript API, onStateChange not firing, no autoplay

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

I have a training program where I'm trying to display a YouTube video in an iFrame, automatically play it, and advance to the next page when the video completes.  I can get the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function to fire, but none of the other events will.  Actually, I'm only interested in state change.

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    tag.id = 'apiScript';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

...

```
    //function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {  //tried this too but no change
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        player = new YT.Player('externalComponent', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onError': onPlayerError,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        console.log('api ready');
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log('onStateChange');
        console.log(YT.PlayerState);
    }
```

When it runs, you can see "api  ready" in the console but nothing else.  iFrame looks like:

```
    <iframe id="externalComponent" src="https://youtube.com/embed/_S_Bg9qfa8o?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&autoplay=1" width="1024" height="576" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What is stopping onStateChange from working and not automatically playing?  The controls do not show.

Comment: It should work. Find below the working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/0oe9wqmh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get it to work as I've posted.  I had to change the code to use a div rather than an iframe, add a video ID and other parameters in the playerVars.  Once I did that, the video played automatically, showed no controls, and fired the state change event.

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                autohide: 1
                },
      videoId: '_S_Bg9qfa8o',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

...

```
<div id="player"></div>
```